# .findViewById() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

So, I am trying to use a Switch in my Android app's SettingsFragment but it seems the IDE just won't see it in the XML. I used the debugger and it seems root.findViewById(R.id.physicalEffortSwitch) returns null.. it just doesn't make any sense.. anyone please?
This would be my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="100dp">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/physicalEffortSwitch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
        android:paddingVertical="17sp"
        android:text="@string/show_jobs_that_require_physical_effort"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="@string/off"
        android:textOn="@string/on"
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveChangesButton"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:text="@string/save_changes"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my SettingsFragment code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    private View root;
    private boolean physicalEffortPosts;
    public static int range;
    public static boolean physicalEffort;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        setup();

        return root;
    }

  private void setup(){

        Switch physicalEffortSwitch = (Switch) this.root.findViewById(R.id.physicalEffortSwitch);
        physicalEffortSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                physicalEffort = physicalEffortSwitch.isChecked();
            }
        });

  }
```

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart, would be my first go to

Comment: Now that I did this, Switch tag in XML was red underlined saying it overrides some other method, hit run again and I'm back to nullpointer and the red line;s not appearing anymore

Comment: Are you sure fragment_settings.xml is your layout you post?

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead `this` to get context in `fragment` .

Comment: Your question text says `physicalEffrotSwitch` but your code says `physicalEffortSwitch`. Is there just a typo?

Comment: @TylerV yup, just a typo.

Comment: @CôngHải you can see that root inflates right fragment

Comment: @TylerV sorry but bad idea

Comment: We can't actually see that root inflates the right fragment since we don't know what the filename of that xml you posted is. Add your import statements to the Java part too - is it possible you imported the wrong "Switch" class?

Comment: @TylerV belve me, the name is the right one. But indeed, I was using wrong type of Switch. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good. I'll add that as an answer so it is archived for future searchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the `Switch` class you imported in your java file is the correct one (e.g. the same one you used in the xml). This often happens with `Toolbar` (there are at least two, and if you import the wrong one and things don't work right/can't be cast and end up null).